# Array Index out of bounce in C# when string in splited

Tags: c#-4.0

hello friend this is my code which i am using following code for splitting the string

```
            string s = dt.Rows[0]["tstrim"].ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length-1; i++)
                {
                var val = s.Split(',')[i];
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select Value,Details from Travelling_Master where Value='" + val + "'", connLive);
                    SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                    da1.Fill(dt1);
                    if (dt1 != null)
                    {
                        string val1 = dt1.Rows[0]["Value"].ToString();
                        if (val1 == "$1")
                        {
                            v1 = "Check Registerd CallerId.";
                        }
                        else if (val1 == "$7")
                        {
                            v2 = "Selecting Query From Customer.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }
                        label2.Text = v1 + "," + v2;
                    }
                }
```

At this line error occurred when it come after last string spiting

```
var val = s.Split(',')[i];
```

array index is out of bounce 
this done when i am getting string from database and updating into another table
so please help for solved this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, currently `i` can take every value within the length of `s` - and you're assuming that there are that many elements *after splitting*.

You should split once, and then iterate over that:

```
string s = dt.Rows[0]["tstrim"].ToString();
string[] bits = s.Split(',');
foreach (string val in bits)
{
    ...
}
```

In general you should prefer `foreach` when you don't *need* the index within the collection.

Also, it's far more conventional to write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
```

than

```
for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length - 1; i++)
```

... exclusive upper bounds are very common in computer science, and it's worth getting used to them.

**Important note**

There's something else very wrong with your code, but not directly related to the exception you're seeing. You're currently building up a SQL string by concatenating a value in the middle of it:

```
new SqlCommand("select Value,Details from Travelling_Master where Value='" + val + "'", 
               connLive);
```

Don't do that. Really, really don't do that. Use parameterized SQL instead:

- It avoids [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- It avoids conversion issues (particularly with dates and times)
- It makes your code clearer (the SQL is just SQL, and the values are values)

Comment: bt its an window application